# angular 2 http withCredentials

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm am trying to use withCredentials to send a cookie along to my service but can't find out how to implement it.
The docs say "If the server requires user credentials, we'll enable them in the request headers" With no examples.
I have tried several different ways but it still will not send my cookie.
Here is my code so far.

```
private systemConnect(token) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('X-CSRF-Token', token.token);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post(this.connectUrl, { withCredentials: true }, options).map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(uid => {
        console.log(uid);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try to change your code like this

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
```

and

```
this.http.post(this.connectUrl, <stringified_data> , options)...
```

as you see, the second param should be data to send (using `JSON.stringify` or just `''`) and all options in one third parameter.

Comment: It is already inside the comments for Headers and RequestOptions source files )

Until official API docs are not ready - we have to use comments in source code instead )

Comment: This is now out of date due to HttpClient being the standard

Comment: The right solution with HttpClient is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304912/angular-4-setting-withcredentials-on-every-request-cors-cookie

Comment: by passing withCred server can set the cookie for cross domain, what if i am using script tag and loading the script, in that case nodejs can set the cookie? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951915/not-able-to-set-the-cookie-from-script-tag-javascript-nodejs

Answer (score 33):

Starting with Angular 4.3, [HttpClient and Interceptors were introduced.](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b)

A quick example is shown below:

```
@Injectable()
export class WithCredentialsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}

constructor(
      private http: HttpClient) {

this.http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.forecasts = result;
    },
    error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Remember to **provide** the interceptor to your app module, as the [article](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b) says:

> In order to activate the interceptor for our application we need to provide it to the main application module AppModule in file app.module.ts:

Your `@NgModule` will need to include this in its providers:

```
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: WithCredentialsInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }],
  ...
```

Answer (score 10):

Creating an `Interceptor` would be good idea to inject stuff into header across the application. On the other hand, if you are looking for a quick solution that needs to be done on a per request level, try setting `withCredentials` to `true` as below

```
const requestOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': "my-request-token"
 }),
 withCredentials: true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for **Angular 17** using an interceptor:

**`credential.interceptor.ts`**

```js
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';

export const credentialsInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (request, next) => {
  const modifiedRequest = request.clone({
    withCredentials: true
  });
  return next(modifiedRequest);
};
```

**`app.config.ts`**

```js
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';

import { provideHttpClient,
         withFetch,
         withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';

import { credentialsInterceptor } from './credentials.interceptor';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    // ...
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([credentialsInterceptor])),
  ]
};
```

Side note: You can also generate interceptor using `ng generate interceptor credentials`.