# Add authentication to OPTIONS request

Tags: api, angular, cors, token, jwt

How can I add headers to the `OPTIONS` request made towards a cross-domain API?

The API I'm working against requires a JWT token set as `Authorization` header on all requests.

When I try to access to the API Angular first performs an `OPTIONS` request that doesn't care about my headers that I setup for the "real" request like this:

```
this._headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token-here'
});

return this._http
            .post(AppConfig.apiUrl + 'auth/logout', params, {headers: this._headers})
            ...
            ...
```

When no token is provided, the API returns HTTP status 401 and Angular thinks the `OPTIONS` request fails.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

According to the CORS [specification when a preflight request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol) is performed user credentials are excluded.

> (...) using the method OPTIONS, and with the following additional constraints:
>
> - (...)
> - Exclude the author request headers.
> - **Exclude user credentials.**
> - (...)

<sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>

With this in mind, the problem seems to be on the API side of things, which **should be accepting `OPTIONS` requests without requiring authentication**.

Comment: The source is a living standard and no longer has the quoted text. Is this Answer still correct in 2021?

Comment: At the present time, in section 3.2.5 (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials) it's mentioned:

_"Note that even so, a CORS-preflight request never includes credentials."_

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for "user credentials" and was very confused. And also am not great at reading english, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cloudformation template, you have to declare `AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight` as `false` like in this example:

```yaml
MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: !Ref Stage
    Auth:
      Authorizers:
        CognitoAuthorizer:
          UserPoolArn: !GetAtt UserPool.Arn
      DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
      AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with,x-requested-for'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
```

This will allow OPTIONS to accept requests without authorization headers

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to provide authentication for CORS preflight requests using the `withCredentials` option:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615675/166850