# Why is my Bearer Token from Angular not visible in Firefox

Tags: angular, http, authentication

My  function looks like this:

```
  testFunctionAuth() {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(AppConfigService.settings.apiServer.rest + 'systems/all', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ...rxbwcO-w' } })
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res);
        },
          err => {
            console.error(err);
            reject(undefined);
          });
    });

  }
```

But I get a 401 back and in the Header, the Auth token is even missing:

[image]

What is also strange is that Firefox says the Method is OPTIONS and not GET. Why?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The OPTIONS request is performed without the authentication header as according to the CORS specification.** However your backend seems to verify the user credentials but as you don't have the auth token in header, the server returns a [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) (Unauthorized).

*from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723041 :*

> According to the CORS [specification when a preflight request](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request) is
>   performed user credentials are excluded.
>
> > (...) using the method OPTIONS, and with the following additional constraints:
> >
> > - (...)
> > - Exclude the author request headers.
> > - **Exclude user credentials.**
> > - (...)
>
> <sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>
>
> With this in mind, the problem seems to be on the API side of things,
>   which **should be accepting `OPTIONS` requests without requiring
>   authentication**.