# Angular 4 - setting withCredentials on every request - cors cookie

Tags: angular, http, cookies, oauth-2.0, cross-domain

My angular client is separated from the backend and I have enabled cors on the backend, everything works fine except the fact that my authentication fails because the cookie is not added to requests.

After searching online I found that I should set `{withCredentials : true}` on every http request. I managed to do it on a single request and it works, but not on all the requests.

I tried using BrowserXhr [How to send "Cookie" in request header for all the requests in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angular2) but it doesn't work and it's also deprecated afaik.

I also tried RequestOptions but it didn't work.

What can I do to set `{withCredentials: true}` on every http request?

Later Edit:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private csrfService: CSRFService) {

  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token = this.csrfService.getCSRF() as string;
    const credentialsReq = req.clone({withCredentials : true, setHeaders: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token } });
    return next.handle(credentialsReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the code that worked for mea

Comment: see my [example](https://github.com/chainly/review/blob/master/docs/4.front/cors.md)

Comment: **Angular 17** solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77581348/42659

Answer (score 51):

You can use an `HttpInterceptor`.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Next you have to provide it:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor ,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Source and full explanation](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin Apologies, I updated my answer with code examples.

Comment: Note that this only works if you're doing requests with @angular/common/http, not with @angular/http.

Comment: This only appears to work for get requests, any advice on post and put?

Comment: @MGDavies The `HttpInterceptor` is not limited to `GET` requests and should also work for `POST` and `PUT`.

Comment: @ThomasWana Do you know how I could add that functionality with @angular/http?

Answer (score 0):

Another perhaps more simple way is to create your own **ApiService**.  It would use an injected `HttpClient`.  All XHR requests would use the ApiService instead of HttpClient directly.

Here is an example implementation:

https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/63f5cd879b5e1519abfb8307727c37ff7b890d92/src/app/core/services/api.service.ts

Some of the code that I have modified:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    withCredentials: true // to allow cookies to go from "https://localhost:4567" to "http://localhost:5678"
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  private formatErrors(error: any) {
    return throwError(error.error);
  }

  get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

  put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      this.httpOptions
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

  post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      this.httpOptions
    ).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }
```